# I need help understanding partial derivation of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I am learning about numerical optimization and I got stuck at this transformation:

[image: derivative computation]

delta is Kronecker delta:

[image: Kronecker delta]

What I can't wrap my head around is how does first line translate to the second. Why/how is x(j) reduced from the expression?

Aditional info: this expression is using the Einstein notation.

Comment: Let's unpack things. You have $\delta^i_k Q_{ij} x^j$, which really means the double summation

$$\sum_j \sum_i \delta^i_k Q_{ij} x_j = \sum_j Q_{kj} x_j$$

where $x_j$ is the $j$-th coordinate of the vector $x$. Equivalently, in the summation notation, this is just $Q_{kj} x^j$; since $j$ is just a dummy variable it can be replaced by $i$.

Comment: When using Einstein notation, $\delta$ renames an index. For instance, $\delta^i_j T_{ik}=T_{jk}$. You can check this by explicitly writing out the implicit sum, but you get used to "just doing it" rather quickly.

Comment: I'm not sure, but sometimes people like to switch dummy-indices (without mention, and it causes confusion) as to help with simplification, and it seems to be the case here. Do you understand the effect the Kronecker delta has on the $Q_{ij}$? If so, see if you can switch a dummy index (hint, it's the one being summed over) on one of the terms in order to arrive at the second line. If not, what happens to the product $\delta^i_k Q_{ij}$ in the cases when $i \neq k$ and $i=k$.